# How to roll back ETL procedure?

Tags: etl, data-warehouse

what is the normal strategy people use to roll back all records of a batch load ? in case for example the ETL procedure breaks midway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WE generally mark that batch fail .

While next time etl execute it should start picking data after last success full run.

Some rear scenario we have to delete records manual (in case we have not handled upset case properly )